# iOS 4.2, looking for a way to manipulate the iPhone 4 camera's focus distance

Tags: iphone, camera, ios-4.2

I am working in an AR project, and we want to manipulate *the focusing distance* of the iPhone4 camera.  Is this even possible?  So far, we've found just toggling and auto focusing as options listed here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureDevice/isAdjustingFocus

Thanks in advance for any tips! :)

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the API it seems that the only supported actions are:
- check if AF is supported on the device (iPhones 3GS an 4 only I think)
- enable/disable AF
- set the point-of-interest that is NOT the distance, but only a point in the camera view.

Certainly not what you want to do.

Might be supported in private API... but that would not pass the validation process.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround might be to see how much pixels move as the user shifts slightly, to get a sense of how distant some parts of the image are, and then set the AF point to a region of the image either closer or further based on that.

But, also file a Radar ticket requesting access to specify the focus distance if possible - if enough people ask Apple will add it to the API.